# Compactness and continuity of positive trace class and linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Let $H$ be a real separable Hilbert space.

Consider the space $\mathcal{B}$ of positive self adjoint linear operators $T$ on $H$ with $\mathrm{tr}(T) \leq 1$.

I am wondering in what sense $\mathcal{B}$ is compact? Additionally,
consider a linear map of the form
$$
f(T) =\mathrm{tr}(TS),
$$
where $S$ is some fixed, positive operator. What conditions on the topology and $S$ are needed such that $f$ is a continuous map?

A good reference for this type of question would also be quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown that $$|{\rm tr}\,(TS)|\le ({\rm tr}\,S) \,\|T\|$$ Hence $f$ is a continuous linear functional on $B(H),$ provided ${\rm tr}\,S<\infty.$  On the other hand we have
$$|{\rm tr}\,(TS)|\le \|S\|\,{\rm tr}\,|T|$$ so $f$ is a continuous linear functional on the space of trace class operators.

Concerning compactness the space of trace class operators is the dual space of the space of compact operators. By the Banach-Alaoglu theorem the unit ball in the space of trace class operator is compact with respect to the weak $*$-topology. The set mentioned in OP is a weak $*$-closed subset of the unit ball. Hence it is compact with respect to the weak $*$-topology.

The  reasoning above can be compared with $c_0^*=\ell^1,$ and $(\ell^1)^*=\ell^\infty,$ where the spaces play the roles of compact , trace class and bounded operators, respectively.